# bigquery load custom record delimiter

Tags: csv, google-bigquery

Is it possible to load delimited files which do not use newline as a record delimiter.

We have been provided with files in cloud storage where fields are delimited by by ascii-1 (can easily do with `-F` option) and the records are delimited with ascii-2. The files are massive, so would rather not text subsitute them if we don't have to.

I cannot find any way to change the record delimiter. Am I missing something? or is it hardcoded to be newline?

Comment: Looking at the [CSV Options](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv#csv-options), it seems only the field delimiter can be specified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like it can be done. Record delimiter is always newline.